# Center multiple rows across selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a slew of reports in Excel using VBA. I hide all columns that are after the used columns. I would like some of the rows to center across the visible columns.

For example, assuming the last column of the report is in column I, I hide J:IV (in Excel 2003). I want one section of the report with data in column A to center across A:I. Can I do that using VBA without looping through each row?

I assume the best way to get the last visible column is with .End(xlRight) (correct me on that if I am wrong, please).

Comment: Just realized I can add the CenterAcrossSelection to a whole range, so the question is really not too relevant. .Range(.Cells(rngReport.Row + rngReport.Rows.Count + 1, 2), .Cells(rngReport.Row + rngReport.Rows.Count + UBound(arrCensus), lastColumn).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection